# Deriving Thue's lemma from Minkowski's convex body theorem

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to find an alternative proof of Thue's lemma, stating that for $ p \in \mathbb{N}, a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^* $

$$ \text{The congruence } x \equiv ay \pmod{p} \text{ has a non-zero solution such that } |x|,|y| <\sqrt{p}$$

So I tried using Minkowski's convex body theorem in the following formulation:

$$ \text{Let } L \text{ be a lattice in } \mathbb{R^d} \text{ and } K \text{ - a convex set symmetric w.r. to 0} $$

$$ \text{If } \lambda(K) \geq 2^d\text{Vol}(L) \text{, then } K \text{ has a non zero lattice point} $$

By lattice I mean an additive group generated by some vectors spanning $\mathbb{R}^d $ and its volume - an absolute value of the determinant of a matrix spanned by those vectors.

Of course the set $ \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : ~|x|,|y| \leq \sqrt{p}\} $ is both convex and symmetric with respect to 0. Its volume is $ 4p $. Now all I need to do is find two vectors $ \alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2), \beta=(\beta_1,\beta_2) $ such that the determinant:

\begin{vmatrix} \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 \\ \beta_1 & \beta_2 \end{vmatrix}

is not greater than $ p $ and that if

$$(x,y) = n\alpha + m\beta ~~\text{ for some integers }n,m$$

then  $x -ay \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

The problem is I can't think of a good way to find such vectors. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it looks like I'm going to answer my own question:

it is enough to take the lattice spanned by $  \alpha = [p,0], \beta = [a,1] $. Its volume is then equal to $ p $, giving us the desired statement